# Why does this XDocument fail validation?

Tags: xml, xsd

Given the schema (anonymised, the key points of interest are renamed and the rest omitted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="inspec"
    targetNamespace="the_right_namespace"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:element name="inspec">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="a_scalar_property" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:element name="a_collection_property">
          <xs:complexType>
            <snip>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="another_collection_property">
          <xs:complexType>                
            <snip>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>                       
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and the instance (declared using VB xml literals):

```
Dim xDocument = 
<x:inspec xmlns:x='the_right_namespace'>
<a_collection_property/>
<another_collection_property/>
</x:inspec>
```

validation fails with the message `The element 'inspec' in namespace 'the_right_namespace' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'a_scalar_property'.`

Why? The `all` element, according to W3Schools:

"The all element specifies that the child elements can appear in any order and that each child element can occur zero or one time."

Omitting `a_scalar_property` is the same as including it zero times. Why does this document fail to validate?

And don't say things like 'post the full code' - this is not my IP and I have anonymised it for a good reason. There is very little else to it, and I have tested with this minimal example, it gives the same result.

Comment: Relevant: http://w3fools.com/ (I'm not saying they would necessarily be wrong in this case.)

Comment: Thanks - I've not found W3Schools to be much use myself, but included it as a reference that probably everybody has heard of - and you'd really hope the first sentence on the page about a fundamental piece of Xml Schema would be correct!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the `minOccurs="0"` for every optional element in `xs:all`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="inspec"
    targetNamespace="the_right_namespace"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
    <xs:element name="inspec">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="a_scalar_property" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="a_collection_property" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <!-- snip -->
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="another_collection_property" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <!-- snip -->
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems stupid that I have to bother - what's the point of `<xs:all>` if I still have to annotate each element anyway? Still, solves the problem.

Comment: Glad to help. `xs:all` just solves the "in any order" part ... and you are probably still left to encounter the joys when you need "any order" AND "zero, one or more".

Answer (score 2):

To make an element optional, the minOccurrs attribute should be 0, even in an <all> group. Getting that from reading the XML schema specification is really cumbersome, but relying on w3schools is not a good alternative.

Comment: [Documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256182) is misleading in the same way: *"Allows the elements in the group to appear (or not appear) in any order in the containing element."*